# I am searching for a C++ code implementing the complex polygamma function

Tags: c++, special-functions

I googled about some code on the complex polygamma function especially C++ code, but can't find anything. Does anyone know where to find such code?

The complex digamma function does exist but not the complex polygamma function.

Comment: Boost has a special functions module. The documentation does not specifically mention if it supports complex arguments, but the signature is: `template <class T>
calculated-result-type polygamma(int n, T z);` which leads me to believe that `z` could be complex.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_gamma/polygamma.html

Answer (score 10):

I implemented a complex polygamma function in the Julia standard library (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/7125).   It is possible to call this from C++ by [linking to the libjulia library](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/embedding/).

The easiest way to do this is to call Julia's `@cfunction` construct to get a C/C++ function pointer to the compiled function.  Then you can call it normally like any other C++ function.

In particular (1) download and install Julia, (2) launch Julia and use its [package manager](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/) to `add SpecialFunctions` (to install the Julia [SpecialFunctions.jl package](https://github.com/JuliaMath/SpecialFunctions.jl) that now contains my `polygamma` code), (3) compile your C++ code linked with `libjulia`.  For example, the following C++ program loads Julia and gets a C++ function pointer `polygamma` to call the Julia polygamma function on `std::complex<double>`:

```cxx
#include <julia.h>
JULIA_DEFINE_FAST_TLS() // only define this once, in an executable (not in a shared library) if you want fast code.

#include <complex>
typedef std::complex<double> (*polygamma_ptr)(int m, std::complex<double> z);
polygamma_ptr polygamma = NULL;

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    jl_init();

    // get a C function pointer to the Julia polygamma function compiled for
    // (int, complex<double>) arguments:
    jl_eval_string("import SpecialFunctions");
    jl_value_t *ret = jl_eval_string("@cfunction(SpecialFunctions.polygamma, ComplexF64, (Cint, ComplexF64))");
    polygamma = (polygamma_ptr) jl_unbox_voidpointer(ret);

    // example: call polygamma(3, 1.7+4.2i) and output it.
    std::cout << "polygamma(3, 1.7+4.2i) = " << polygamma(3, std::complex<double>(1.7, 4.2)) << "\n";

    jl_atexit_hook(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `polygamma(3, 1.7+4.2i) = (-0.0184344,0.0162077)`.

Comment: is there any template how to incorporate these special functions in C++? 
I have looked into the manual and also some questions related to it in stackexchange but no answer.

Comment: The easiest way is to call Julia and use it's `@cfunction` construct to get a C/C++ function pointer to the compiled function.  Then you can call it normally like any other C++ function.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at what the python scipy library does for its special functions, the polygamma is found by returning the digamma if the zeroth derivative is requested, otherwise return $(-1)^{n+1}\Gamma(n+1)\zeta(n+1,z)$ where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function and $\zeta$ the two argument Riemann zeta function. Assuming that this identity holds for the complex numbers, it may explain why you can't find any explicit code.

In fact to add a reference, this is also the method used in the gnu implementation of libstdc++, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a01203.html)